# Konva Transformer restrict shape size

Tags: html5-canvas, transformer-model, konvajs

I don't think it's possible currently to restrict the size of a shape when using Transformer to make it bigger or smaller but I really need to add this capability.

What is the best way to go about doing this ourselves (giving the size of shapes min/max which Transformer will honour) ?

Thanks.

Comment: Just added this issue to GitHub: https://github.com/konvajs/konva/issues/360

Comment: Thanks lavrton, after re-reading my question I'm not sure if I was clear what I am trying to achieve with Konva. e.g I need to have max and min so when my shapes are being scaled with transformer they can't be less than 60 or bigger than 200 - I only enable middle-right and middle-left btw. I expect the way to do this currently would be by catching the dragmove events for the middle-right or middle-left anchors which I am doing and then resetting the size of my shape somehow if max or min exceeded which I can't do currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var MAX_WIDTH = 200;
rect.on('transform', function() {
  var width = rect.width() * rect.scaleX();
  if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
    var scaleX = MAX_WIDTH / rect.width();
    rect.scaleX(scaleX);
  }
})
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/xowihazaza/2/edit?html,js,output